# can you use pigeon to annotate all images in a folder

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, annotations, data-annotations

I would like to label images within a folder with either yes or no for a machine learning project.

I found this great tool; Pigeon..
https://github.com/agermanidis/pigeon

but the examples provided online requires the user to provide the names of all files within the script. I have not been able to find a way to point the script to a folder instead of including all image names.

Is there a way where you can just provide a link to a folder only.

```
from pigeon import annotate
from IPython.display import display, Image

annotations = annotate(
  ['assets/img_example1.jpg', 'assets/img_example2.jpg'],
  options=['cat', 'dog', 'horse'],
  display_fn=lambda filename: display(Image(filename))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to just list all files in the folder you are interested in. In this case you provide just the path to the folder (absolute or relative) and use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get all the files in that folder.

I then use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to get the file paths and pass a list of the file paths to `annotate`.

```
from pigeon import annotate
from IPython.display import display, Image
import os

path = "assets"
imgs = os.listdir(path)
imgs = [os.path.join(path, img) for img in imgs]

annotations = annotate(
  imgs,
  options=['cat', 'dog', 'horse'],
  display_fn=lambda filename: display(Image(filename))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a for-loop that went through a folder and populated a list with the image names. Then just called the list in place of

```
['assets/img_example1.jpg', 'assets/img_example2.jpg']
```